# Select certificate for authentication pop up handling in selenium java with edge browser

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Tried to login to an application where SSO login is enabled. Once after click on the SSO login button its asking to select the User for login in a pop up. Browser used is Edge(91-version). Tried to handle with alert class, driver options but didn't worked.

Can anyone suggest any solution.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: I had the same issue in Firefox, solved with setting to choose automatic imported certificate and using dedicated browser profile. But I'm not sure if same would work with Edge.

Comment: Please provide the screenshot of the pop up and the [minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you use which can **reproduce the issue**. So that we can have a better understanding of the issue and we can have a test and see how to help. With only the above text description, we can't locate the issue.